# Make Specific words bold in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am wanting to know how to find specific words in a text label and make them bold.

For example `descriptionTxt.Text` contains several words 'Step 1:, Step 2: and so on ...

I want to find the literal text "Step", followed by a space, then one or more digits, followed by a colon" and make this bold.

***C# Code***

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string ID = Request.QueryString["id"];
                RecipeID.Text = ID;

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
                con.Open();
                try
                {

                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Recipe_Name, Recipe_Description, Recipe_Instructions FROM Recipe Where Recipe_ID= @recipeid", con);
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@recipeid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = RecipeID.Text;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        nameTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    descriptionTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                    instructionsTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();

                    dt.Clear();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

                con.Close();
            }
```

Comment: _"want to find these"_ - define **these**. Once you can define in English which words you want to bold, turning that to code is trivial.

Comment: What does "etc" mean, **exactly**? Please be specific. And what have you tried? A regular expression like `"Step [0-9]+:"` seems to do what you want...

Comment: @CodeCaster Do you not know what etcetera means? Its means so on and so fourth. Like the list continues. Step 1, Step 2, Step 3, Step 4, Step 5, Step 6, Step 7 and then it continues to however more Steps there may be.

Comment: Please read my previous two comments again. "Etc" is too vague, not concrete enough to implement. A sentence like _"I want to find the literal text `"Step"`, followed by a space, then one or more digits, followed by a colon"_ is clear and trivially implementable.

Comment: @CodeCaster Okay sorry i do apologise for being too vague. Do you understand now what i am asking to find out?

Comment: Yes, it's unambiguously clear now (as you see on the -two- one existing answers, that _was_ a problem). Happy to help clarify your question.

Comment: @CodeCaster how do i add a regular expression like what you suggested in C#.

Comment: Please update the question I want to release my downvote

Comment: @Veverke what does that mean?

Comment: In order for me to be able to remove the downvote I casted here, the OP has to edit the question, otherwise the vote is kept locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you describe lends itself for a regular expression.

In this case the expression `(Step [0-9]+:)`, meaning *"The literal text "Step", followed by a space, then one or more digits, followed by a colon"*:

```
var stepRegex = new Regex("(Step [0-9]+:)");
```

Now to "make bold" as you ask, you can use HTML as we can assume an HTML context from your ASP.NET tag. This is as trivial as wrapping the found value with `<b></b>` tags, using `$1` to refer to the matched group.

```
string content = "Step 1: do something. Step 2: see step 1.";
string replaced = stepRegex.Replace(content, "<b>$1</b>");
```

This will yield `"<b>Step 1:</b> do something. <b>Step 2:</b> see step 1."`.

Also, you don't want to assign this HTML to a Label control, use a Literal instead.

Comment: So if i would want to make this work with descriptionTxt.Text then would i just add content = descriptionTxt.Text ?

Answer (score -1):

```
descriptionTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString().Replace("Step1", "<b>Step1</b>");
```

Comment: While correct, answers on Stack Overflow are expected to contain more than just code, meaning you should **explain** why this code would work and how to use it.